# MATLAB query about for loop, reading in data and plotting

Tags: matlab

I am a complete novice at using matlab and am trying to work out if there is a way of optimising my code. Essentially I have data from model outputs and I need to plot them using matlab. In addition I have reference data (with 95% confidence intervals) which I plot on the same graph to get a visual idea on how close the model outputs and reference data is.

In terms of the model outputs I have several thousand files (number sequentially) which I open in a loop and plot. The problem/question I have is whether I can preprocess the data and then plot later - to save time. The issue I seem to be having when I try this is that I have a legend which either does not appear or is inaccurate.

My code (apolgies if it not elegant):

```
   fn= xlsread(['tbobserved' '.xls']); 
   time= fn(:,1); 
   totalreference=fn(:,4);  
   totalreferencelowerci=fn(:,6);  
   totalreferenceupperci=fn(:,7);  
   figure  
   plot(time,totalrefrence,'-', time, totalreferencelowerci,'--', time, totalreferenceupperci,'--');  
   xlabel('Year');  
   ylabel('Reference incidence per 100,000 population');  
   title ('Total');  
   clickableLegend('Observed reference data', 'Totalreferencelowerci',  'Totalreferenceupperci','Location','BestOutside');  
   xlim([1910 1970]);  
   hold on  
   start_sim=10000;  
   end_sim=10005;  
   h = zeros (1,1000);  
   for i=start_sim:end_sim %is there any way of doing this earlier to save time?  
   a=int2str(i);  
   incidenceFile =strcat('result_', 'Sim', '_', a, 'I_byCal_total.xls');  
   est_tot=importdata(incidenceFile, '\t', 1);  
   cal_tot=est_tot.data;  
   magnitude=1;  
   t1=cal_tot(:,1)+1750;  
   totalmodel=cal_tot(:,3)+cal_tot(:,5);  
   h(a)=plot(t1,totalmodel);  
   xlim([1910 1970]);  
   ylim([0 500]);  
   hold all  
   clickableLegend(h(a),a,'Location','BestOutside')    
   end
```

Essentially I was hoping to have a way of reading in the data and then plot later - ie. optimise the code.

I hope you might be able to help.

Thanks.

mp

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your issue concerning

> I have a legend which either does not
>   appear or is inaccurate.

have a look at the following extracts from your code.

```
...
h = zeros (1,1000);  
...   
a=int2str(i);  
...
h(a)=plot(t1,totalmodel);  
...
```

You are using a *character array* as index. Instead of `h(a)` you should use `h(i)`. MATLAB seems to cast the *character array* `a` to `double` as shown in the following example with `a = 10;`.

```
>> double(int2str(10))
ans = 49    48
```

Instead of `h(10)` the plot handle will be assigned to `h([49 48])` which is not your intention.